# How can I receive environment params from docker-compose.yml on java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, scheduler

I'm doing a Java application with Spring Boot and will receive a cron scheduler from docker-compose.yml.
In NetBeans, I can read the values from application.yml, but when I deploy the image on docker server, I can't receive this params.

docker-compose.yml

```
  integracao-spot:
    container_name: integracao-spot
    image: yuricolen13/integracaospot
    restart: always
    environment:
      jobs_produto_cron: '0 40 9 * * *'
      jobs_estoque_cron: '0 42 9 * * *'
      jobs_vendas_cron: '0 44 9 * * *'
```

application.yml

```
jobs:
  produto:
    cron: '0 33 16 * * *'
  estoque:
    cron: '0 34 16 * * *'
  vendas:
    cron: '0 35 16 * * *'
```

EstoqueJob.class

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class EstoqueJob {

    public String diretorioLocal = "";
    public String diretorioBucket = "cliente/indiana/indiana/diario/";
    public String lojas = "(5,7,11,50,85)";

    @Scheduled(cron = "${jobs.estoque.cron:-}")
    public void estoqueJob() throws SQLException, IOException {
        
      System.out.println("JOB SCHEDULED");

}
```

Read params from docker-compose.yml

Comment: Your example should work. What does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following application.yml

```
jobs:
  produto:
    cron: ${jobs_produto_cron}
  estoque:
    cron: ${jobs_estoque_cron}
  vendas:
    cron: ${jobs_vendas_cron}
```

Keep in mind according to best practices for naming conventions, environmental variables have to be named with upercase letters. ex `JOBS_PRODUTO_CRON`

Also in your `docker-compose.yml` you have to provide the values as list with `-`.

```
 ...
 environment:
      - jobs_produto_cron: '0 40 9 * * *'
      - jobs_estoque_cron: '0 42 9 * * *'
      - jobs_vendas_cron: '0 44 9 * * *'
```

Comment: When a do one space between "-" and "jobs_...", the docker return error at the compose file.

Without this space, they understand like a env param.

I made the ajusts in application.yml and docker-compose, but still don't working.

The @Scheduling annotation on method is right?

Comment: @YuriColen what is the proof it does not work?

Comment: @YuriColen keep in mind that `System.out.println("JOB SCHEDULED");` might not be visible since scheduler runs in a different thread than main application. Add a proper logging library for the logger to be always seen.

Comment: the `System.out.println("JOB SCHEDULED");` is just for show if the schedule works on exemple. In my application, will run a query on DB and create a .csv file.

When I run the application, with cron defined in application.yml on NetBeans, works well!
After this test, I builded with dependecies, build the docker image, push to docker hub and pull on docker server.
The application runs, but don't work the scheduler.
I try set default cron on application and build together, but still don't working.
summing up... the scheduler just works at IDE